# Magento 2 : How to Update Price After Changing Qty On Cart

Tags: magento2, cart, price, qty

How to update price after qty changed by dropdown in magento 2.
I changed qty input type to dropdown like below code in `default.phtml`:

```
 <td class="col qty" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>">
       <div class="field qty">
                <select id="cart-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo $_item->getId() ?>-qty" name="cart[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>" data - cart - item -
                        id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        echo $_item->getSku() ?>">
                    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $qty; $i++): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"<?php if ($i == $block->getQty()) {
                            echo 'selected';
                        } ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                        <//?php $i = $i + 4; ?>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
```

As above how to get changed value and update price in cart.

like 
[image]

please help.

Comment: did you find solution?